# .htaccess 301 redirect PLUS url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wordpress, rewrite, 301-redirect

Premise:

- My photography website is www.domain.com and my blog is on www.domain.com/blog.
- Everything is on self hosted wordpress platform.
- On my index page I have my photo galleries.
- I now would like to use a third party service to host my galleries at www.galleries.com/me.

What I would like to achieve:

- when someone visits www.domain.com it gets redirected 301 to www.galleries.com/me but keeps my domain visible in url address
- when someone visits www.domain.com/blog everything stays as usual and nothing changes.

What I thought:

- usa redirect rule PLUS a rewrite rule on my .htaccess

Questions:

- Is it possible?
- How can i do it?
- How does it affects SEO?

I tried to make it as simple as I could :)
Thanks

Comment: The very definition of a 301 is that the address bar changes.  You may be able to get the behavior you want with a reverse-proxy setup (where all connections come to your server, then for certain pages it creates a new connection to galleries.com to fetch the content) - would something like this work for you situation?

Comment: Thanks Shane. Sounds like it should work. How can i make it happen?

Comment: Depends - do you have access to any Apache config files, or just `htaccess`?

Comment: @ShaneMadden  htaccess only..

Answer (score 1):

You could try [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) to run a proxy for www.galleries.com/me. Be sure to read the red boxes on the docs page. Also you'll want to check that the service allows this.

Alternatively, you could find a hosted service that allows you to use your own domain (you could use subdomain perhaps e.g. gallery.domain.com) or you could install an FOSS gallery package.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've no access to the normal config context, the normal method of just using `ProxyPass` is of no use.

Try this, in an `.htaccess` in the site's root:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Don't redirect for anything in /blog.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog [NC]
# Everything else, proxy to www.galleries.com/me
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.galleries.com/me/$1 [P]
```

Comment: Doesn't do anything.. white page :(

Comment: Interesting.  Does it redirect you if you turn the `[P]` to `[R]`?  If that works but `[P]` doesn't, then you provider might not have mod_proxy loaded in their Apache configuration.